# Best physics engine with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, physics-engine

I'm building a simple program.  Basically some simple meshes, some cubes, etc. I'll be having them crash around a bit through (against some solid objects).  I've worked with a couple of rendering engines but nothing like what I want (i.e. like, with physics :] ).

Comment: did my answer not furfil your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try http://sourceforge.net/projects/vbphysxdx9/

It uses PhysX by Nvidia. You will need a Nvidia graphics card with PhysX to use it though.

Comment: the problem is, the people I plan on releasing this too may or may not have Nvidia cards.  I don't even have one (After getting it refurbed 4 times, I switched to an ATI).

Comment: you can give this a try http://www.ode.org/
please do mark this as an answer if it furfils your original requirement.